# Search string from JAR file global in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am developing stomp+WebSocket using Intellij Idea. Now I need to know: how to search string from Intellij Idea global? For example, I got this error:

```
15:17:44.688]-[clientInboundChannel-59]-[org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler]-{Searching methods to handle SEND /app/vehicle session=qnlerizz}
15:17:44.688]-[clientInboundChannel-59]-[org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler]-{No matching methods.}
```

And I go to class `WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler` in spring-websocket.jar(Maven's jar) and find nothing about this string:`No matching methods` or `Searching methods to handle`. So I want to search where the message is. How to do?

What I have tried is the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> but It does not work fine, I can't search from external jar. Double <kbd>Shift</kbd> can only search class.

Comment: Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72213415/316343

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Go <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

or

**Navigate -> Symbol..** from menu

- Give your text to search.

Comment: But it can not search from external jar,like maven dependency jar file

Comment: I have tried your way,it works.That's what i want.I do not know how to express my appreciate.Thank you!

Comment: @Dolphin are you able to perform search in external jars like maven dependency?

Comment: Cmd + Shift + F (on Mac), click `Scope`, then put your keyword. It works. @DHRUVBANSAL

Answer (score 2):

In mac try <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>F</kbd>, click scope, enter the keyword to search.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this -> [How to search for a string in JAR files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331025/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-jar-files) can help you.

For external library(jar) you can use this way

> Looks like 'Find in Path', 'Custom Scope' set to 'Project and
> Libraries'

Comment: This is the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

JD-GU http://java-decompiler.github.io, you can search text in jar.

Drop all your jars file into it and "Ctrl + Shift + S" it will search in all files

[image]